# Big O of inverse function plus constant

Tags: asymptotics

if I have a function

$$f(i) = \frac{a}{1 + bi} + c,$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive constants, and $i \geq 1$ is an integer.

Can I say

$$f(i) = O(1/i)$$

Wiki says that $f(i) = O(g(i))$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ iff $|f(i)| \leq M|g(i)|$ for all $i > i_0$. This means in my case

$$\frac{a}{1 + bi} + c \leq \frac{M}{i}, \forall i > i_0$$

But as $i \rightarrow \infty$ the fractions approach $0$ and so it's saying $c \leq 0$, which is not the case. So is it instead correct to say $f(i) = O(1)$?

Comment: One way to *see* things like this--especially when the expression of $f$ is more complicated--is to expand them in Taylor series around $\infty$; that is, in terms of $1/i$: $$f(i) = c+\frac{a/b}{i}\left(1 + (-1/b)i^{-1} + (-1/b)^2i^{-2} + \cdots + (-1/b)^ni^{-n} + \cdots\right).$$ This was computed using the Binomial Theorem, which also shows it converges absolutely for $|bi|\gt 1$.  The result is immediate--and you get much more detailed information about the rate of convergence, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $f$ is $O(1)$. Note that

$$\frac{a}{1 + bi} + c < a + c,$$

which can be taken as M. [Note also that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) for any $M>0$

$$\limsup_{i\rightarrow \infty} \Bigg \vert \frac{f(i)}{M} \Bigg \vert  = \frac{c}{M}.$$